# SetInterval inside scrolling events on iPhone - Why this code doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, iphone, events, scroll, setinterval

Please, take a look at this code (I'm using Zepto http://zeptojs.com/ BTW)...

```
var timer = false;

$(window).bind('touchstart touchmove scroll', function (e) {
    if (timer === false) {
        timer = setInterval(function () {
            $('footer').css('top', (this.pageYOffset + this.innerHeight - 40) + 'px');
            console.log('Adjusted...');
        }, 100);
    }
}).bind('touchend', function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = false;
    console.log('Cleaned it up...');
});
```

As you can see, I have a footer element that I'm trying to keep fixed on the bottom of the iPhone screen. I know that there are libraries that helps us make this quite easily like iScroll 4 http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4, but I was trying to see if I could make it simpler.

It turns out that the code above doesn't work properly. While I'm actually scrolling the page, for some reason setInterval doesn't execute but instead seems to pile up on the background to run every call at the same time.

At the end it doesn't do what I wanted it to do, which is to "animate" the footer and have it in place during scroll not only after. Does anyone has any idea on how such effect could be achieved on some similar manner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> When you pass a method to setInterval() (or any other function, for that matter), it will be invoked with a wrong this value. This problem is explained in detail in the JavaScript reference.

[MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your outer callback, `this` will be the DOM element you care about, but inside the `setInterval` callback, `this` will be `window`. Keep in mind that [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/this) is a keyword, not a variable, and that it is highly context sensitive.

The usual approach is to capture the value of `this` in a variable and then use that variable instead of `this`:

```
if(timer === false) {
    var self = this; // "_that" is also a common name for the variable.
    timer = setInterval(function () {
        $('footer').css('top', (self.pageYOffset + self.innerHeight - 40) + 'px');
        console.log('Adjusted...');
    }, 100);
}
```

Similar issues apply to all callbacks in JavaScript, always make sure you know what `this` is and grab its value and build a closure over that value when it won't be what you want.

Comment: True! Actually I knew I was missing that but forgot to add. The thing is that, event fixing _this_, it doesn't work as expected. The setInterval function still holds until it stops scrolling execute every function call...

Comment: I've changed my code to not rely on events and just execute the setTimeOut all the time and the issue is there. Maybe it's a limitation from the software and there is no way around it (which would suck)?

Comment: @Eber: Is this fiddle doing what you're expecting? http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9rKNf/

Comment: Not really... As it turns out, iOS blocks any DOM modifications when scrolling, so that really isn't possible to do :(

Comment: @Eber: What if you replace the `append` with a `console.log` and turn on the Mobile Safari log?